# How do I properly use fopen and fopen_s, and what is the difference? My code is not compiling properly

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm writing a basic seating reservation program in C for a school project that uses file handling in order to save and load data. Whenever I try to run the program, I recieve errors telling me that fopen is not safe, so I used _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and it still does not work. I am not as experiecned in coding as many others, so that's why I came here. I am hoping someone could explain to me how to properly work around this problem so that it won't happen in the future.

Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
// ...

void saveData(SEAT seats[], int seatNum) {
    FILE* file = fopen("seat_config.dat", "wb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fwrite(seats, sizeof(SEAT), seatNum, file);
        fclose(file);
        printf("\n\nData saved to file: seat_config.dat");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nERROR: Unable to save data to file.\n\n");
    }
}

void loadData(SEAT seats[], int seatNum) {
    FILE* file = fopen("seat_config.dat", "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fread(seats, sizeof(SEAT), seatNum, file);
        fclose(file);
        printf("\n\nData loaded from file: seat_config.dat\n\n");
    }
}
// done
```

`SEAT` is a struct that contains the seat id number, occupied status, first and last names of occupants.

There are probably other parts that I am missing but this is where Visual Studio is indicating that there's a problem.

I have also included below my library.h header file which contains all of my functions:

```
#pragma once

void initializeSeat(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
void printmenuchoice();
void emptySeats(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
void assignSeats(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
int lastnameCompare(void* a, void* b);
int firstnameCompare(void* a, void* b);
void alphasortSeat(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
void deleteSeats(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
void saveData(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
void loadData(SEAT seats[], int seatNum);
```

Comment: Please consult the man page for [fopen_s()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-170). It is `errno_t fopen_s(FILE** pFile, const char *filename, const char *mode);` which is nothing like `fopen()`. That page shows an example.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28691612/20017547

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` must be before any includes, ideally the first line of any file that includes anything. You could also define it in your project to avoid having to sprinkle it everywhere.

Comment: I put four of those right at the top: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`, `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`, `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`. The first three silence MSVC's false claims about "deprecated functions".

Comment: Did your code work, and you are asking about the warnings? Function `fopen()` is alive and well in the upcoming C23 standard. By caving into Microsoft's demands, you'll sacrifice code portabilty. They want to tie you to their product.

Comment: ... but it still warns about functions which really *are* deprecated. When I try to use the obsolete `gets()` MSVC provides a warning (but compiles it for backward compatibility).

Comment: thank you guys for helping, but I put '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS' and it still gives me the error

Comment: You need **`#define`** `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` *before* `#include <stdio.h>` or any other `#include`.

Comment: yes that's what I did. I put it before all my #include in each of my .c and .h files

Comment: You shown a part of the code, and things that are irrelevant to the problem. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows your use of `fopen()` that produces compiler warnings. About a dozen lines should do it.

Comment: Relevant post: [How to use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450423/how-to-use-crt-secure-no-warnings)

Comment: You can say you added the define, but until I see it in a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue I just don't believe you. When used correctly I've never had a problem so I assume that however you're doing it is incorrect in some way.